# Passing ** as an argument

Tags: f#, functional-programming, operators

Let's say I want to calculate the sum of `2^n` for `n` ranging from 0 to 100. I could write the following:

```
seq { 0 .. 100 }
|> Seq.sumBy ((**) 2I)
```

However, this does not behave like `(*)` or other operators/functions. The problem is the fact that F# uses `(*` and `*)` to delimit comments and my usage of the exponentiation operator is identified as such. I know I could instead say

```
Seq.sumBy (fun n -> 2I ** n)
```

or even

```
Seq.sumBy (( **) 2I)
```

but the former is a little more verbose than necessary and the extra whitespace in the latter is a huge eyesore for me.

Is there a standard way to handle the aforementioned usage of `(**)`? Perhaps some kind of escaping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical way is to use

```
( ** )
```

which avoids comment parsing.  The `( **)` variation could cause problems when nested inside a `(* ... *)` comment block

Comment: Thank you. Does this kind of notation then apply to all other operators or is this the odd one out?

Comment: This is just about the only one, because of the comment thing.

Comment: @nphx Not this exact problem, but `::` isn't usable as a function, and its variant `List.Cons` strangely isn't curried. `(*)`, on the other hand, works both inside and outside of comments.